# Why doesn't Redirect() execute in controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I'm in Method1().  A condition in the method is met so Redirect() code executes:

```
//SalesController
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Method1(SalesViewModel model)
{
//some code here

if (condition) {
  return Redirect(localhost:3000/page1.html);
}

return View("SalesGraphDisplay", model);
```

The URL I end up on is not `localhost:3000/page1.html` but instead `localhost:3000/Sales/Method1`.

How is that possible?  The view is not returned so the redirect is where I should end up right?

Answer (score 0):

Saw that your are referring to a page in same solution i guess?

1: You can create a cshtml file and controller? Doesn't change much for the HTML file I guess.

2: Create a FilePathResult, never tried, but read about it.

```
 return new FilePathResult("~/page1.html", "text/html");
```

Comment: The conditional is working as expected.  I have breakpoints and have been checking it.  The issue is something else.  In fact, I even removed the return View() and still get the same result.